# Why I'm not being able to apply the .json() method to a Response object when the Response status is other than 200?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the following function

```
async function favoriteGatos() {
const response = await fetch(API_URL_FAVOURITES);
console.log(response);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data)

if (response.status !== 200) {
    spanError.innerHTML = "Hubo un error: " + response.status + data.message;

} else {}
```

}

When everything is going well and the http status for the fetch response is 200 the object 'data' will be created with no problem, but when something goes wrong, for exaple the API key is wrong, creating a response with a http status code different from 200, I can no longer apply the .json() method to the response and the code breaks at that point showing the following message on the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'A', "AUTHENTICA"... is not valid JSON
```

Comment: Well if the server would send a JSON response with non-200 status code, you could use `.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can no longer apply the .json() method

Because the response body isn't JSON data.  It's likely just text, so you'd use `response.text()` instead.

As to *why* the server is returning different data formats depending on the HTTP code, that's a debate to have with whoever maintains that server.  But the observation from your end is that an HTTP 200 (or similar) returns JSON, whereas any error codes return text.

In that case you'd have to check the response code before trying to deserialize the data:

```
async function favoriteGatos() {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL_FAVOURITES);

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    const data = await response.json();
    spanError.innerHTML = "Hubo un error: " + response.status + data.message;
  } else {
    const data = await response.text();
    // handle the error response in some way
  }
}
```